# SQL IF Case and using Variables

Tags: sql, magento, variables, if-statement, case

I am trying to change some quantities in our magento database with this command:

```
SELECT @var,(@var:=qty*-4) FROM cataloginventory_stock_item WHERE product_id = 1;
UPDATE  cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty=qty+@a WHERE product_id = 2;
UPDATE  cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty=0 WHERE product_id = 1;
```

I was trying to wrap an if-case around that all (only update catalogetc~ when the qty is <0).
But I think I'm doing something terribly wrong somewhere.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT @var,(@var:=qty*-4) FROM cataloginventory_stock_item WHERE product_id = 1;
UPDATE  cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty=qty+@a WHERE product_id = 2 AND qty > 0;
UPDATE  cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty=0 WHERE product_id = 1 AND qty > 0;
```